# STM32 UART character encoding issues (can't decode using either ASCII or UTF-8)

Tags: stm32, uart, stm32f4, hal-library, encoding

first some specifics:

STM32F411 Nucleo board, 
Atollic TrueSTUDIO v9.1.0, 
Debian linux 9.6.

I am sending a telemetry string over the UART using the HAL.  I am using the following code to construct and transmit the data:

```
sprintf(str, "#, %d, %d, %s\n", csvString.range, csvString.lux, csvString.time);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, str, strlen(str), 100);
```

where '#' is the telemetry sentence start character, and the data follows a pre-formatted CSV type structure for easy manipulation on the receiving side.  If I do a simple

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

I can see the output, which looks like:

```
#, 21, 114, 01:58:001
```

so that looks like it's working well.  However when I attempt to use a simple python script to parse this information in, I get a mess.  It appears to be an encoding problem.  The python that I'm using looks (as an excerpt) like this:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout=2, parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN, bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

if ser.isOpen():
    ser.close()

ser.open()
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
line = ser.readline(100)

ser.close()
```

and the result I get out of this reading of 100 bytes off the UART (just a sniff to see if things are working properly) looks like:

```
#\t\x920\t\x8a1\x13\t\xa22\xa7\xb2:\x820\xe1#\t\x922\t\x8a1\x13\t\xa22\xa7\xba:\x821\xe1#\t\x921\t\x8a1&\t\xa22\xa7\xba:\x821\xe1#\t\x923\t\x8a1&\t\xa22\xa7\xba:\x821\xe1#\t\x921\t\x8a1&\t\xa22\xa7\xba:\x821\xe1#\t\x920\t\x8a1\x13\t\xa22\xa7\xba:\x82
```

There is an obvious repeating pattern in this, which looks like it lines up with the telemetry sentences.  I can't use some of the other methods in python to read off the UART easily because they can't detect newline characters in this.

It's obviously an encoding problem, but I'm not sure how to solve this as:

- I do not know how to (even after searching) verify the transmit encoding used by the STM32 HAL/Compiler
- I am not a talented software person

Could the community please:

- Help me determine what the encoding being sent is
- Give an example of how to decode it so that I can then write code to parse things as I need to

Thanks!

EDIT:
To address a comment suggesting evaluating the UART data using an oscilloscope, I can not do this as I am using the UART bridge on the STLink part of the STM32 Nucleo board.  I am not currently able to switch to the other UART as those pins are in use.  It would also not account for why I can see the data properly formatted if I display the output of the device in a terminal session (the above mentioned cat /dev/ttyACM0).  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If an uart looks rubbish, check the baudrate.  There is no encoding in an uart, it send what *you* put in.

Comment: It's certainly not an encoding problem in the sense of ASCII vs UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1. For the characters you are using, there's no difference between these encoding. My guess is it should be `parity = serial.PARITY_NONE` (instead of `parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN`).

Comment: Maybe it is a python encoding thing, but I am not an expert in this. If you first try to receive the data with a simple terminal programm like (Hterm, ...) you can see if the transmission is working.

Comment: connect an oscilloscope and check the UART output against a sample from a pc.

Comment: Also, make sure your clock is what you believe it to be

Comment: Is the UART ever idle, or is it transmitting continuously?

Comment: Just because you are using the on-board STLINK does not mean you cannot probe the UART signals with a scope; they are there for you to access.  Because your question lacks the source code which configures the UART, it's not really answerable.  You should examine the source code which configures the port, or use a scope, or use a terminal program where you can see the configured settings to figure out what those need to be.  It's extremely unlikely you have parity enabled on the STM32, unless you explicitly set that in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do a simple
>
> `cat /dev/ttyACM0`
>
> I can see the output

So it is working with the default settings of `/dev/ttyACM0`. You can find out what they are with the `stty` command. On my PC I get

```
root@berendilinux:~# stty -a </dev/ttyUSB0 
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
root@berendilinux:~#
```

Run `stty -a </dev/ttyACM0` on your host, and whatever rate it reports would be the baudrate to put in the Python program.

Read `man stty` for the meaning of the flags. My output contains

```
`-parenb cs8 -cstopb`
```

that means *no parity*, 8 bits, 1 stop bit. Parity is rarely used these days, some hardware does not support it in 8 bits mode at all.

Comment: What's the reference for `no parity, 8 bits, 1 stop bit` Where do you get this information from?